# Android ERROR : wrong 2nd argument type

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Пробовал делать через обычный фрагмент, так и не завелось, выходит ошибка `"wrong 2nd argument type"` , указывает на `frag`, ошибка в строчке ftrans.replace(R.id.container, frag);

```
@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    FragmentTransaction ftrans = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
        ftrans.replace(R.id.container, frag);
        // Handle the camera action
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    } ftrans.commit();
```

`frag` у меня ссылается на класс фрагмента.

Если делать так: `getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,frag).commit();`

То выходит такая ошибка :

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                              java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   com.example.hondle.biling.MainOnlineActivity@41335ad0 must implement
>   OnFragmentInteractionListener
>                                                                                  at
>   com.example.hondle.biling.fragments.FragPay.onAttach(FragPay.java:84)

UPD3: В качестве суперкласса используется AppCompatActivity

UPD4: Изначально использовал [этот туториал](http://www.fandroid.info/navigation-drawer-activity-v-android-studio-struktura-shablona-primer-raboty-dizajn-android-prilozhenij/)

Comment: в какой строке ошибка?

Comment: Зарегистрируйтесь на сайте, тогда вы сможете редактировать свои вопросы и дополнять их подробностями.

Comment: Какого типа у вас объект frag? Если это фрагмент из библиотеки поддержки support, то вам вместо getFragmentManager надо использовать getSupportFragmentManager

Comment: А в качестве суперкласса для вашей активити вы какой тип используете? AppCompatActivity или ActionBarActivity?